# Nav fits 100% of VP

Tags: html, css

I just noticed now that my nav bar doesn't fill all the page size and also it has a scroll bar at the end. I want to make that nav and the rest of the items to fill the 100% of the viewport. How can I get rid of the blank space that is generated at the right side?

Here's my codepen https://codepen.io/dfonsecar/pen/abyNWXd

````
 <header>
   <nav>
     <a class="gradient-text" href="#home">dfnr</a>

     <ul class="nav-list">
       <li>
         <a href="#home">Home</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href="#">About</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href="#">Services</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href="#">Contact</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
 </header>
 <main>
   <div class="main-text" id="home">
     <p class="text-title">Hi! This is</p>
     <h1 class="title gradient-title">DIEFONRO</h1>
     <p class="pos-text">Junior Front-End Developer</p>
     <button class="hire">HIRE ME</button>
     <button class="get-cv">GET CV</button>
     <img src="gif.gif" alt="diefonro's ilustration" class="main-img">
   </div>

   <!-- <div class="about">
       <img src="img1.png" alt="dev" class="dev-about">
       <h2>LET ME INTRODUCE MYSELF</h2>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quasi molestias cumque eos inventore nemo ducimus, dolorum, quos dignissimos cum error molestiae impedit. Deleniti consectetur eum eligendi aspernatur dolor beatae quasi?</p>
   </div> -->
 </main>
</body>

 * {
margin: 0;
}

html{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
}
nav {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
background-color: #fff;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.266);
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
}
.gradient-text {
float: left;
background-color: rgb(83, 10, 112);
background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, #5479f2, #6116a7);
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: repeat;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-moz-background-clip: text;
-moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.gradient-title {
background-color: rgb(66, 10, 104);
background-image: linear-gradient(
 310deg,
 #5479f2,
 rgb(8, 77, 141),
 rgb(15, 99, 209),
 #6116a7
);
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: repeat;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-moz-background-clip: text;
-moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

a.gradient-text {
font-family: "Pangolin", sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 1.5rem;
padding: 7px;
margin-left: 20%;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(2, 2, 2, 0.144);
letter-spacing: 5px;
}

ul.nav-list {
list-style: none;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 0 0 13%;
}

ul.nav-list li {
display: block;
font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
letter-spacing: 4px;
float: left;
margin: 0 5px;
font-size: 0.9em;
}

nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #333;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}

nav a:hover {
color: black;
}

nav a:active {
background-color: #f0eeeea1;
color: black;
}

.main-text {
text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.301);
}

.text-title {
font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
font-size: 2em;
font-weight: 600;
position: relative;
top: 200px;
left: 300px;
margin-top: 5px;
color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.title {
font-family: "Pangolin", sans-serif;
font-size: 5em;
letter-spacing: 5px;
position: relative;
top: 200px;
left: 300px;
color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
margin-top: 10px;
font-weight: 700;
}

.pos-text {
font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
font-size: 1.3em;
font-weight: 600;
position: relative;
top: 200px;
left: 300px;
margin-top: 5px;
letter-spacing: 3px;
color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
}

.hire,
.get-cv {
position: relative;
top: 200px;
left: 300px;
border: none;
width: 150px;
margin-top: 25px;
padding: 13px;
border-radius: 7px;
font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
font-weight: bolder;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 7px rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.52);
box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.404);
letter-spacing: 5px;
float: left;
}

.hire{
color: #6116a7;
border: 1px solid #571e8d3b;
}

.get-cv {
margin-left: 15px;
color: #6116a7;
border: 1px solid #571e8d3b;
}

.hire:hover,
.get-cv:hover {
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #5479f2, #6116a7);
color: #fff;
}

.hire:active,
.get-cv:active {
background: linear-gradient(45deg, #1e48d1, #480686);
color: #fff;
}

img.main-img{
width: 700px;
float: left;
position: relative;
top: -90px;
left: 280px;
z-index: -1;
}
/* 
.about{
clear: both;
}

img.dev-about{
width: 40px;
} */```

Also an image 


https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HfHs.png
````

Comment: try adding display: inline-block;; to .main-text

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `position: relative;` for elements inside `.main-text` and replace css `left`/`top` to `padding`.